# How to use multiple include/exclude creiteria simultaneously in powershell?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am using the following code to get files using include & exclude criteria:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Path/To/Folder -Include @("*Basic_TShirt_Men*",) -Exclude @("*black*","*purple*")
```

The above code filters files whose names contain `Basic_TShirt_Men` and doesn't contain `black` or `purple`. I need to modify the code to search by these criteria:

Criteria 1: Filename includes Basic_TShirt_Men and doesn't contain black or purple `OR`
Criteria 2: Filename includes Basic_Polo_Shirt and doesn't contain blue `OR`
Criteria 3: Filename includes Basic_Shirt_Women and doesn't contain pink

How to combine multiple `Include/Exclude` criteria like above?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, you need an extra layer of filtering:

```
$include = @(
    '*Basic_TShirt_Men*'
    '*Basic_Polo_Shirt*'
    '*Basic_Shirt_Women*'
)

Get-ChildItem Path\To\Folder\* -Include $include |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Name -like '*Basic_TShirt_Men*' -and $_.Name -notmatch 'black|purple' -or
        $_.Name -like '*Basic_Polo_Shirt*' -and $_.Name -notlike '*blue*' -or
        $_.Name -like '*Basic_Shirt_Women*' -and $_.Name -notlike '*pink*'
    }
```

Note, the use of the trailing `\*` after the path should be there for `-Include` to work properly.